# ¿Porque el ciclo for de mi función itera cada 2 elementos de la lista?

Tags: python

Quiero crear una función que indique si una cadena contiene todas las letras del abecedario por lo menos una vez:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    alpha_list = list(alphabet)

    for i in alpha_list:
        if i in str1:
            alpha_list.remove(i)

    print(alpha_list)
    if alpha_list == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Y devuelve esto:

```
ispangram('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z']
False
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo, la función no elimina todos los elementos de la lista como debería ya que la cadena contiene todas las letras del abecedario.

Comment: Nunca se debe modificar una lista por la que se está iterando. Los resultados son imprevisibles. Es el equivalente a serrar una rama de un árbol mientras estás sentado en ella :-) Para esta tarea yo sugeriría usar conjuntos. La función se quedaría en una línea: `return set(str1.replace(" ", "").lower()) == set(alphabet)`

Comment: Fíjate por cierto que tal como lo tenías sólo eliminas las letras con índice par. Esto es porque el bucle comienza haciendo `i='a'`, detectas que esa letra está y la eliminas, con lo que la lista cambia, y ahora su primer elemento pasa a ser `'b'`, cuando avanzas a la siguiente iteración del bucle pasas a `'c'`, y `'b'` te la has "saltado". Del mismo modo te vas saltando una de cada dos letras, que son las que al final te quedan en `alpha_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampliando un poco la respuesta que te di en un comentario, un enfoque con conjuntos consistiría en convertir a `set()` todas las letras de la frase que recibes como parámetro (pasándolas a minúscula para que sea independiente del caso), y convertir a `set()` también las letras del alfabeto, para después comparar si ambos conjuntos son iguales.

El tipo `set()` se ocupa de eliminar duplicados y también tiene operadores interesantes como la unión, intersección, diferencia, pertenencia, etc.

Un problema es que la frase de entrada puede contener caracteres que no son letras, los cuales no deberían tenerse en cuenta en la comparación. Por ejemplo, los espacios entre palabras. Una vez convertido en conjunto la cadena de entrada, tendríamos los caracteres que la componen, entre los cuales aparecería un espacio lo que haría que la comparación con el conjunto del alfabeto falle (pues éste no contiene el espacio).

Una solución simple podría ser eliminar espacios antes de convertirlo en conjunto, y eso es lo que hice en el comentario. Pero una solución más general puede ser comprobar si el conjunto abecedario es un subconjunto del conjunto de letras de la frase. El operador `<=` entre conjuntos hace precisamente eso. Esta solución funcionará aunque la cadena de entrada tenga muchos otros caracteres no-letra.

Es decir:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
  return set(alphabet) <= set(str1.lower())
```

---

```
>>> ispangram('The quick brown fox? jumps over the lazy dog!')
True

>>> ispangram("Esta no lo es")
False
```

Si se trataba de un ejercicio de clase y no se os permite usar conjuntos, sino que tienes que hacerlo con bucles, debes cambiar el bucle en que vas eliminando letras del alfabeto por otro enfoque, pues eliminar elementos de una lista sobre la que estás iterando tiene resultados imprevisibles. La solución en este caso suele ser la contraria, es decir, comenzar con una lista vacía a la que se van añadiendo elementos que cumplan una cierta condición (en este caso, letras que estén en `str1`). Al final del bucle puedes comparar la longitud de esta lista con la del abecedario, lo que indicaría que están todas.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear algo asi:

```
lista_verificadora = ['a', 'b']
Listado_palabras = ['hola', 'adios']

for palabra in Listado_palabras:
    palabra_separada = list(palabra)
    for caracter in palabra_separada:
        for validador in lista_verificadora:
            if caracter == validador:
                print 'existe ['+validador+'] en ['+palabra+']'
```

Resultado:

```
existe [a] en [hola]
existe [a] en [adios]
```

solo recorro todo mediante ciclo for y con list separa cada palabra en letras para hacer las comparaciones..!!

Comment: No necesitas convertir un string en lista para iterar por sus letras. Puedes hacer `for caracter in palabra`. Tampoco necesitas iterar por la lista verificadora para ver si el carácter está. Puedes hacer `if caracter in lista_verificadora`. Y en todo caso esta respuesta no está relacionada con el problema de la pregunta, ya que se buscaba determinar si una cadena era un pangrama, es decir, si tenía todas las letras del abecedario o no, para lo cual necesitarías un registro de cuáles has encontrado y cuáles no.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede modificar una lista si se está iterando sobre ella, porque esto hace que el "iterador" (en este caso el for) ,al desaparecer el item donde estaba, pierda la posición y crea que esta posicionado en el item siguiente.

En general (y para no cambiar tanto tu código) lo más sencillo es crear una copia de la lista sobre la que se va a iterar y luego borrar sobre la original.

Así quedaría:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    alpha_list = list(alphabet)

    alpha_list_iterator = alpha_list[:]  # crea nueva lista para usar de iterador

    for i in alpha_list_iterator :     #usa la nueva lista
        if i in str1:
            alpha_list.remove(i)

    print(alpha_list)
    if alpha_list == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Resultado:

```
>>> ispangram('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
[]
True
```